# Unable to get total rows from database using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs/Express , Right now i am tyring to get total record from database but i am getting "nothing/empty",Here is my model file code,Where i am wrong ?

```
static async addServiceDetail(shopId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
        const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`;
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql);
         console.log('total rows are'+ rows); // getting empty
        if(rows<1)
            {
                  //further code  
            }
    }
```

Comment: More information is needed. What type of database are you using? SQL, MySql, etc. How are you connecting to the database? Are you using an npm package or a custom connector? Have you checked if your query actually works? Have you checked that all variable have the correct information?

Comment: `console.log(shopId, serviceId)` to see if the values are as you expect. If as expected, then go through your database records and confirm if you have records with their shopId and serviceId columns having the respective values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard without more code but something I notice is your `genderTypeId` should it be in `${}`? :

From :

```
const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`;
```

To :

```
const sql = `SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId='${shopId}' AND  serviceId='${serviceId}' AND genderTypeId='${genderTypeId}'`;
```